# How to create a transaction in Azure Logic App that inside this transaction contains actions?

Tags: c#, sql, transactions, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I need to implement code from C# to logic app. In C#, when performing select UPDLOCK in sourcecode, and after finishing the select, it will perform some other processing such as update, modification. During this process, if there is another select statement for the same data, it will have to wait for the transaction to finish.

So how to write a similar handler in Azure Logic App?

I'm thinking I'll need to use the SQL query connector and do TRANSACTION writing inside it. Or write a stored procedure and execute it. Is there any other way?